# How to skip bandit on multi line queries

Tags: bandit, bandit-python

I am trying to skip multiple line queries using bandit in my python query. I have tried to use `#nosec` but still there is bandit issue showing

Example:

```py
"""#nosec""" ;Query = f"""Select username,id,email_id,address from User where username ='John'"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code you show doesn’t handle Bandit warnings: the first part is a string expression `"""#nosec"""` followed by an assignment statement (and I can’t see why Bandit would complain about that.

Anyway, according to [the docs](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#exclusions) you can exclude specific lines of code using a special comment:

```py
time.sleep(random.random())  # nosec B311
```